# The initial ARP cache for a router that never got a packet

Tags: arp, gns3

I am trying to understand the ARP cache. So, here is the physical structure of my network:
[image]

Note that I did not ping any of the PCs yet. So, I expected the ARP cache of the router R1 to be empty. The screenshot below shows the info about each PC in the network:

[image]

Here I am showing the ARP cache of a router R1. It is not empty, what are these entries for?

```
R1# show arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  192.168.10.1            -   c201.4fd8.0000  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
Internet  192.168.4.1             -   c201.4fd8.0001  ARPA   FastEthernet0/1
```

Comment: "Note that I did not ping any of the PCs yet" – By the way, there is something called a *gratuitous ARP*, where a host sends an ARP Response for its own address without anyone having asked for it. This is used for multiple reasons, including speeding up network discovery (in this case a host would send a gARP as soon as its interface comes up), informing other hosts of an address change (sending a gARP when the address of an interface changes), and redundancy failover (in a cluster where either multiple host have different MAC addresses but share one IP address or share one MAC and IP address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the router has got two interfaces with IP addresses 192.168.10.1 and 192.168.4.1. Those entries are its own interfaces.